# How to make two text files into a dictionary(small fix)?

Tags: python, dictionary

For example,  say I have two text files, test_keys.txt

```
 2
 5
7
```

and test_values.txt

```
ace
ventura
pet detective
```

My code to make these files into a dictionary is as follows.

```
with open('test_keys.txt') as file1:
    keys = file1.readlines()
with open('test_values.txt') as file2:
    values = file2.readlines()
print(sorted(dict(zip(keys,values)).items()))
```

To which I get

```
[(' 2\n', 'ace\n'), (' 5\n', 'ventura\n'), ('7', 'pet detective')]
```

How can I get rid of the \n and the space before the numbers in my result? I tried .replace('\n', '') after file1.readlines() and I get a, 'list' object has no attribute 'replace', error. Any suggestions?

Comment: `keys = map(str.strip, file1.readlines())`?

Comment: `dict(zip(keys,values)).items()` - why the whole `dict(...).items()` part? It seems redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension to convert keys to numbers and strip the values:

```
keys = [int(key) for key in keys]
values = [value.strip() for value in values]
```

Then follow your code.